# Dynamically fill models with more detailed data in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm a bit stuck with implementing master-detail views in emberjs.

Most of my views have a master-view which is just a list of titles. Then, a user can click such title and he/she gets an overlay with the detail-view (somewhat like a typical newsitem page).

Now, I noticed that when ember asks the information for the master-view it calls urls like: `/backend/newsitems`. But these calls can get very heavy because the backend returns a list of all newsitems with all their detailed data. But this feels wrong because the user is only looking at the master-view and didn't request any detailed information yet.

Is there a way to make ember clear that the master-view only needs several attributes and that a request for detailed information should get the extra attributes of that particular item?

Just as an example, my model looks like this:

```
App.Newsitem = DS.Model.extend({
  slug: DS.attr('string'),
  type: DS.attr('string'),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  summary: DS.attr('string'),
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  thumb: DS.attr('string'),
  date: DS.attr('date'),

  mediaitems: DS.hasMany('App.Mediaitem')
});
```

But my master-view only needs `id` `type` `title` to show a list of titles and an icon next to that title.
Then, when a user request the detail of one newsitem all other attributes should be fetched.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by having the server include a 'partial' property in the payload.  'partial' will be true if it's just a partial response, and it'll be false if it's a full response.  I'll also offer a workaround if you're not able to change the server API (and therefore can't include a 'partial' property in the payload).

As others have suggested, in the model hook of the 'detail' route, call the model's reload() method if the currently loaded model is only a partial:

```
App.ItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find('item', params.item_id).then(function (item) {
            if (item.get('partial'))
                return item.reload();
            else
                return item;
        });
    }

});
```

This solved part of the problem, but if your user then navigates to the master route, then Ember Data will replace all fields with the server response and wipes out any property values that weren't returned from the server.  To overcome this, override the store's push method like this:

```
App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({
    push: function (type, data, _partial) {
        if (data.partial && this.hasRecordForId(type, data.id))
            return this.getById(type, data.id);
        else
            return this._super(type, data, _partial);
    }
});
```

This ensures that your partial payload doesn't overwrite the full payload.

Here's a jsbin to demonstrate: http://jsbin.com/bejop/6/edit

If you're not able to include a 'partial' property in the response, then you can apply the same logic as above but look for a specific property in your model that will appear in your detail response, but not in your partial response.  Then when you override the push method, you can do it like this:

```
    App.Partials = [
        { type: App.Item, propertyName: 'detailed_description' }
    ];

    App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({
        push: function (type, data, _partial) {

            var that = this;
            var partial = App.Partials.find(function (p) {
                return p.type === that.modelFor(type);
            });

            if (partial && !data[partial.propertyName])
                return this.getById(type, data.id);

            return this._super(type, data, _partial);
        }
    });
```

Comment: In the `push` function, if the data is partial, maybe the model could be updated instead of returning it from the cache: call `return this._super(type, data, true)` instead of `return this.getById(type, data.id)`. Would it be useful?

Comment: @cbliard, I tried that, but the problem is that the data that is passed into store's push method is already normalized, so it includes all of the missing properties (initialized with the default value, such as null). So asking the store's push method to do a partial update doesn't work, because the payload already contains all of the properties, even the ones that the server doesn't return.  You can see this in the Ember Data code where the promise is resolved.  If you follow the code, it will eventually call the normalize method, which is called before the store's push method.

Comment: @cbliard, I created 2 bins to demonstrate.  Here is the technique that works: http://jsbin.com/bejop/6/edit. Clicking on 'Three Little Pigs' will load the book details, including the 'description' property, which isn't available in the partial response.  Then going back to the 'Books' list will retain the 'description' properly, as it doesn't overwrite it with the default null value.  Here's the same example, but using this._super(type, data, true) in the store's push  method: http://jsbin.com/bejop/5/edit. You'll notice the 'description' is reset to null every time you return to the list.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain, I see the problem with updating the model now.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make ember clear that the master-view only needs several attributes and that a request for detailed information should get the extra attributes of that particular item?

Sure, but perhaps not in the way you are expecting. Ember models are really lightweight, so there is no need to have a 1-1 relationship between them and your backend schema. In general I like the think of ember-models in terms of API endpoints. In this case your API is exposing 2 distinct sets of data, so the most straightforward solution is to create a separate ember model to represent the lightweight list of titles.  This model will have it's own api endpoint at `/backend/newsitem_listings`.

```
App.NewsitemListing = DS.Model.extend({
  slug: DS.attr('string'),
  type: DS.attr('string'),
  title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

With this in place, you can use `App.NewsitemListing.find()` or `App.NewsitemListing.find({query: q})` to fetch some/all of the listings, then `App.Newsitem.find(id)` to load details for an individual record. You might consider adding a relationship such as `newsitem: DS.hasOne('App.Newsitem')` to the model, or you could just use slug to generate links on the fly.

Comment: While this is the best way that I can find to do this in Ember, the major annoyance I'm having with it now is that when you update (or delete) a "NewsItem" the corresponding "NewsItemListing" obviously doesn't know to get updated. 

This means that I have to do a lot of "updating both" to keep things in sync which goes against the ember-way.

Comment: For readers who find this, the other thing to be aware of if you go this route is that your linkTo helper no longer works because you are passing a model of a different type. It'd be great if linkTo accepted an ID instead of the full object, perhaps someone can figure out how to do this?

Comment: Yeah that's a good point - there is probably a workaround but would have to give it some thought. Suggest opening a new SO question about it to see if anyone else has a solution...

Comment: There's rumors that some of the other branches of ember-data are working to address this, potentially even for the 1.0 release. I think it's best, for now, to remove the teasers, get rid of all this non-ember-way code and let them catch up.

Comment: Yeah I've heard the same. Still, seems like should be possible to use linkTo given an ID instead of a full object.

Comment: FYI, it appears with the linkTo facelift in 1.1, it is possible to pass an ID. http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/upcoming-linkto-changes-ideas/1635

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem recently and I hope what I came up with can help you.

My API has a `/books` endpoint which returns an array of objects with several - but not all - fields. When I `GET /books/:id` though, I can every bit of information that there is for the book with the ID `:id`.

Then, in Ember I have this route setup for a single book page:

```coffeescript
App.BookRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    Book.find(params.book_id)

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set("model", model)

    unless model.get('full') is true
      model.reload().then ->
        # We now have all the information.
        # Setting `full` to `true` to prevent loading it again.
        model.set('full', true)
    return
```

So when a User is just browsing the list, the model's fields are mostly empty, but when she then comes to a book detail view, the API is hit and the additional book data is inserted into the same model instance.

Comment: I'm actually having a problem with this approach, as ember-data overwrites all fields when the API response for the list view comes _after_ the detail response (and your additional fields get set to `undefined`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579604

Comment: In your list view route you could write something like this:
`App.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    books = @store.all('book')
    if books.get('length') is 0
      books = @store.find('book')
    return books`