# Ember.js - how to fetch additional record details?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Struggling with populating Ember with data.

I'm using Rails as the backend, and when I hit /contacts.json (ContactsRoute), it returns a list of id, first, last -- works as expected.

However, when visiting a detail view (ContactRoute), I would like to hit /contacts/1.json and fetch details like email address, anniversaries, etc. But since I have a dynamic segment the model hook is skipped and none of the associations are available.

Question: what is the best approach for fetching additional data in a list/detail scenario?

Models:

```
App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  company: DS.attr('string'),
  emails: DS.hasMany('App.Email'),
});

App.Email = DS.Model.extend({
  contact: DS.belongsTo('App.Contact'),
  emailAddress: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Route:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('contacts');
  this.resource('contact', {path: 'contacts/:contact_id'});
});

App.ContactsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  init: function() {},
  model: function() {
    return App.Contact.find();
  }
});

App.ContactRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Contact.find(params.contact_id);
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted an answer to a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18553153/1254484

Basically, in your `App.ContactRoute`, override the `setupController` method:

```js
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set("model", model);
  model.reload();
  return;
}
```

I'm using this with the latest `ember-data` (commit `ef11bff` from 2013-08-26).