# When Loading Detailed Entry and Then List of Entries, Ember Data Removes Fields Not Set In List Response

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `Book` model, with several attributes, e.g. `title`, `author` and `prices`. `prices` is a large list of historical pricing information.

When I request a list of books from the API, I exclude the `prices` field to keep the response small.

On a book detail view, I request the complete book information (and render a chart using d3). ember-data fetches the single book from the API, updates the model and everything is fine.

My book single page is a [nested resource](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources) of my book list resource:

```coffeescript
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'books', ->
    @resource 'book', path: ':book_id'

App.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.Book.find()

App.BookRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    Book.find(params.book_id)
```

When I enter the app on the book detail page (`/#/books/42` instead of `/`), I cannot say which request my API responds to first, the single book or the book list. Sometimes, the single book data is processed first, then the book list data comes in and ember-data overwrites the existing data with the newly retrieved one.

**My problem is this:** The `prices` field, that is not included in the book list response, will be erased from the model record if the book list response is received *after* the single book response.

**Therefore, my question:** Is there a way to prevent ember-data from overwriting fields with `undefined`?

I don't really understand this behavior, too. Is this actually a bug? I see that updating a value which the new API response specifies as `null` makes sense, but replacing values with `undefined` was quite surprising.

---

- I can easily replicate this by telling my API to wait for a few seconds before responding with the list data
- I'm using the latest Ember release (1.0 final!)
- I'm using the latest ember-data from [builds.emberjs.com](http://builds.emberjs.com/latest/ember-data.js)
- `prices` is an attribute of type "raw" (custom), but it is the same if I exclude the `author` field from the list response

---

If there is an alternative to ember-data that solves this, I'm willing to switch to that (if it has no other big drawbacks – I'm currently not even using `hasMany`!)

Comment: Okay, so after updating to Ember-Data 1.0-beta2 the App just waits on startup for all data retrieval (promises) to resolve and that way this problem does not occur anymore in real life. Nevertheless, this is just a coincidence in my application and I think that the core problem, replacing undefined values, still exists.

Comment: So yeah, if you jump into a details view directly (e.g., `#/books/77`) via a bookmark or the like, it still overrides the full details with the partial book info that Ember Data does after on its own. Very aggravating. I am using `hasMany` but that shouldn't matter, and `Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.9+canary.7dccea8dbf`. If anybody solved this question it would be a big help!